# how do you use react-rails react_component with webpacker gem rails 5.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, react-rails

Newbie here, I've recently implemented the webpacker gem in my react-rails project. Being new to webpack and react, this gem makes a lot of sense to me coming from a rails background.

i'm wondering if it were possible to use the react-rails gem  in my rails webpacker project so we could still use the view helper method like this:

```
<%= react_component('MyComponent', @controller_value.to_json)%>
```

if not, is there a reason why?

Thanks for any input! :)

Comment: you can check this out: https://github.com/perezperret/react-rails-expenses ran into it while reading into `webpacker`'s github issues.

Comment: dooooooood very nice! I'm taking a look through your set up, i entirely agree with your thought process in install. :)

Comment: didn't make that repo, but I also agree with the thought process behind it. Cheers!

Comment: oh nice! thanks and good job for giving the proper credit when due :)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install node- [I used nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md),

and install yarn- [link](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install).

Then, add these lines to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'webpacker', '~> 2.0'
gem 'react-rails'
```

then run

```
bundle install
rails webpacker:install
rails webpacker:install:react
rails generate react:install
```

This will create the necessary files in `app/javascript` (not `app/assests/javascripts`) and config files.

Now add `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` to the appropriate layout file, like `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Finally you will need to run `./bin/webpack-dev-server` in a separate terminal, along with `rails server`.

That's it. Now you can use

```
<%= react_component('MyComponent', @controller_value) %>
```

Here `MyComponent` will be defined in `app/javascript/components/MyComponent.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can use another gem for this

```
--> #react_on_rails (5.2.0)
```

$ bundle show react_on_rails
`--> #- /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/react_on_rails-5.2.0`

Isn't the helper supposed to be included something like this?:

See http://pothibo.com/2013/06/customize-rails-view-controller-with-railtie/
and https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/blob/master/lib/react/rails/railtie.rb#L42-L44

**Hear is the example of gem react_on_rails and gem react-rails**

https://learnetto.com/blog/rails-data-react-component-webpacker